# JSON: referencing json schema with id

Tags: json, jsonschema

So I have one json schema and within this schema I am referencing another two schemas within the same json file, this works fine.

```
{
  "id": "http://ourdns.co.za/public/assets/json/formSchema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "id": "#person",
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "title": "What is your first name",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "title": "What is your last name",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "person_api": {
      "type": "object",
      "id": "#person"
    }
  }
}
```

What i would like to have is a root json schema that references two other json schemas that are external to the root. This differs from my current schema where I have all the schemas in one file(not ideal). There is a slight problem in that I cannot use `$ref` as a reference keyword because the plugin we are using [does not support](https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform/issues/54) this. However we have found that `id` can be used as a reference keyword.(JsonForm is the plugin). How would we then get these using the `id` keyword because it does not seem to work?

```
{
  "id": "http://ourdns.co.za/public/assets/json/formSchema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "person_api": {
      "type": "object",
      "id": "public/assets/person.json"
    }
  }
}
```

1) How do we call the same data externally, like.. `"id": "public/assets/person.json"` instead of combining it all in one file?
2) How would we retrieve particular properties for example if we only need `person.firstname` from person.json schema?

```
{
  "id": "http://dsn.co.za/public/assets/json/person.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "title": "What is your first name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot perform referencing with just `id` on its own.  For referencing, you *have* to use `$ref`.

The `id` keyword allows you to supply a URL for the schema as a **target** for referencing:

```
{
    "id": "http://example.com/schemas/example",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "arr1": {
            "id": "#item-schema",
            ...
        },
        "arr2": {"$ref": "#item-schema"}
    }
}
```

This is so that you can reference schemas using nice URLs (e.g. `http://example.com/schemas/example#item-schema`) instead of using JSON Pointer fragment syntax.  It also allows you to re-organise your schema (e.g. move the item schema into `definitions`) without changing the URL.

However, for the referencing itself, you still need to use `$ref`.  If you need this functionality, you need support for it in whatever tool you're using.

Comment: The plug in does not support `$ref`, that is the main reason why I am opting for `id` to reference the file

Comment: As I said in the answer (now edited for clarity), `$ref` is the only way to reference a file.  If your plugin does not support `$ref`, it does not support referencing.